# Pandas (Python Module) - Searching for String in Specific Column

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry if this is a basic question, I just started using the pandas module today. But basically I'm using it to clean up this csv file I'm working with. I'm trying to search for a specific string (or substring) in the second column and if I find it I wanted to add a new column to the dataset that will either contain a boolean value of true/false (for if I found the given string or not). Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Series.str.contains()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method:

```
df['new'] = df.iloc[:, 1].str.contains(r'substring', flags=re.I)
```

Demo:

```
In [40]: import re

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
   a       b   c
0  1    Anna  10
1  2  Barton  11
2  3     Max  12

In [42]: df['new'] = df.iloc[:, 1].str.contains(r'ma', flags=re.I)

In [43]: df
Out[43]:
   a       b   c    new
0  1    Anna  10  False
1  2  Barton  11  False
2  3     Max  12   True
```

Comment: that worked, thank you! i was just wondering what the "r" before the string does/why it's necessary?

Comment: also, is there a way to search for the string but have it be case insensitive?

Comment: @123, in this particular case it's not necessary, but it might be useful for more complex regular expressions

Comment: Please take at least 30 seconds to read up http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html. If you don't find your answer, then ask further.